# mongoose aggregate $convert fieldname with spaces

Tags: string, mongoose, double, aggregate

I'm trying to convert a string field to double while aggregating on a field name that has spaces in it.

But the input field **$+sumField** resolves to **$Total Incl Vat** with spaces and this is not correct I suppose and it doesn't return the actual sum.

Anyone have a solution?

Example data

```
{_id: 1, "Total Incl Vat": "1550.96", customer: 1},
{_id: 2, "Total Incl Vat": "2000", customer: 1},
{_id: 3, "Total Incl Vat": "1000", customer: 1}
```

Aggregation

```
 const sumField = "Total Incl Vat";
 const $group = { 
                _id: null,
                total: {
                    $sum: {
                        $convert: {     
                            input: "$" + sumField,
                            to: 'double',
                            onNull: 0,
                            onError: "Error"
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

 const result = mycollection.aggregate([
     { $match: { customer: 1 }}, 
     { $group }
 ]);
```

The aggregation result gives 0 as result which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$toDouble](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/) operator. Here is the aggregation you're looking for:

```
mycollection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      customer: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      total: {
        "$sum": {
          $toDouble: "$Total Incl Vat"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ItjKc31TSyi

And if you want to display just the total with a dollar sign, you can further project it like so:

```
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: false,
      total: {
        "$concat": [
          {
            $literal: "$"
          },
          {
            "$toString": "$total"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Which will result in:

```
[
  {
    "total": "$4550.96"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed one can also use $toDouble, I found a bug in the fieldname, it was a field from a subdocument, so I needed to prepend the subdocument name to my query $ + 'payload.' + fieldName .. :) Now its working perfectly!